# D3.js multi-line graph

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, d3.js

Here is my JS code which uses the [D3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3) library (mostly snipped from other examples). I want to graph the acceleration of a point in 3D-space which changes with respect to time. The X-axis of the graph is `timestamp` and the Y-axis is the `x`,`y` and `z` location of the point. Is there a way to write this more efficiently?

This code is a PHP page loading data from a MySQL database called `data` which contains the table `accel_data`. `accel_data` contains 5 columns:

- `timestamp(TIMESTAMP)`
- `cal_acc_x(double)`
- `cal_acc_y(double)`
- `cal_acc_z(double)`
- `sleep_id(int)`

Acceleration data in 3 axis are sent from an accelerometer and kept into the `accel_data` table via a separate mechanism. The PHP needs a `$_REQUEST` `sleep` which is the `group_id` of the data collected.

The data is then parsed to the javascript as `var data`, an array of objects; each object contains `timestamp`, `x`, `y` and `z`. (e.g. in JSON format: `[{"timestamp":"2016-10-31 22:59:59", "x":3.99, "y":4.01, "z":8.11},...]`).

The graph does multiple things. Firstly, it displays the data of the 3 axis as a multi-line graph of x, y and z. Secondly, it displays a legend of the graph on the left-top area. Lastly, it displays a hover line (`hoverLine`) and focus rings (`focusX`, `focusY`, `focusZ`). The '`-6`' you may see with `d3.event.layerX` is the offset I found by experimenting.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Graph Sleep Data</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>        
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura');
    #visualization {
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
    }

    .path {
        stroke-width: .5;
    }

    .axis {
        shape-rendering: smoothEdges;
        stroke-width: .5;
    }

    .x.axis line {
        stroke: lightgrey;
    }

    .x.axis .minor {
        stroke-opacity: .5;
        font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
    }

    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }

    .axis text {
        color: dimgray;
        font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14;
    }

    .label {
        font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18;
    }

    .y.axis line,
    .y.axis path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
    }

    .grid .tick {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .grid path {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .legend {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    rect {
        stroke-width: 2;
    }

    .overlay {
        fill: none;
        pointer-events: all;
    }

    .focus circle {
        fill: none;
    }
    .focus text {
        font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14;
        color: dimgray;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Graph of Data in 3 axes</h1>

<?php
        $servername = ########;
        $username = ########;
        $password = ########;
        $dbname = "data";
        $tablename = "accel_data";
        $data_array = array();

        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if($connection->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: ".$connection->connect_error);
        } 
        $sleep_id = isset($_REQUEST["sleep"]) ? (int) $_REQUEST["sleep"] : die("\"sleep\" is not specified...<br>Aborting...");

        $sql = "SELECT `timestamp`,`cal_acc_x`, `cal_acc_y`, `cal_acc_z` FROM $tablename WHERE sleep_id=$sleep_id";

        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data = new StdClass;
                $data->timestamp = $row["timestamp"];
                $data->x = (double)$row["cal_acc_x"];
                $data->y = (double)$row["cal_acc_y"];
                $data->z = (double)$row["cal_acc_z"];
                $data_array[] = $data;
            }
        } else {
            die("No data for sleep=".$sleep_id);
        }
        $connection->close();
?>

    <svg id="visualisation"></svg>

    <script>
        var WIDTH = 1000,
            HEIGHT = 500,
            MARGINS = {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 60
            };

        var vis = d3.select("#visualisation").attr("width", WIDTH).attr("height", HEIGHT);

        var data = <?php 
        echo json_encode($data_array);
    ?>;

        var format = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.timestamp = format(d.timestamp);
            console.log(d.timestamp)
        });

        var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
            return d.timestamp;
        }));
        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(data.map(function(o) {
            return Math.min(o.x, o.y, o.z);
        })), d3.max(data.map(function(o) {
            return Math.max(o.x, o.y, o.z);
        }))]);

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale),
            yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

        xAxis.tickSize(MARGINS.top + MARGINS.bottom - HEIGHT); // Vertical Grid lines

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(['#BC4747', '#82BC47', '#474FBC'])
            .domain(['x', 'y', 'z']);

        vis.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        vis.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);

        vis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", -HEIGHT / 2)
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Acceleration (m/s²)");

        vis.append("text")
            .attr("x", 101)
            .attr("y", 17)
            .attr("font-size", "16px")
            .attr("font-family", "'Jura', sans-serif")
            .attr("font-weight", "bold")
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Sleep = <?php echo $sleep_id?> ");

        var lineGenX = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return xScale(d.timestamp);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return yScale(d.x);
            });

        var lineGenY = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return xScale(d.timestamp);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return yScale(d.y);
            });

        var lineGenZ = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return xScale(d.timestamp);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return yScale(d.z);
            });

        vis.append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "path")
            .attr('d', lineGenX(data))
            .attr('stroke', color('x'))
            .attr('stroke-width', 2)
            .attr('fill', 'none');

        vis.append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "path")
            .attr('d', lineGenY(data))
            .attr('stroke', color('y'))
            .attr('stroke-width', 2)
            .attr('fill', 'none');

        vis.append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "path")
            .attr('d', lineGenZ(data))
            .attr('stroke', color('z'))
            .attr('stroke-width', 2)
            .attr('fill', 'none');

        var hoverContainer, hoverLine, hoverLineGroup;

        hoverLineGroup = vis.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "hover-line");
        // add the line to the group
        hoverLine = hoverLineGroup
            .append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", 10).attr("x2", 10) // vertical line so same value on each
            .attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", HEIGHT) // top to bottom  
            .attr('stroke', 'GREY')
            .attr('stroke-width', 0);

        // hide it by default
        hoverLine.classed("hide", true);

        var overlay = vis.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("width", WIDTH)
            .attr("height", HEIGHT)
            .on("mouseover", function(event) {
                focusX.style("display", null);
                focusY.style("display", null);
                focusZ.style("display", null);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(event) {
                focusX.style("display", "none");
                focusY.style("display", "none");
                focusZ.style("display", "none");
                handleMouseOutGraph(d3.event);
            })
            .on("mousemove", function(event) {
                mousemove(d3.event);
                handleMouseOverGraph(d3.event);
            });

        var handleMouseOverGraph = function(event) {
                var mouseX = d3.event.layerX - 6;
                var mouseY = d3.event.layerY - 6;

                if (mouseX >= 60 && mouseX <= WIDTH && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= HEIGHT) {
                    // show the hover line
                    hoverLine.classed("hide", false);
                    hoverLine.attr('stroke-width', 1);

                    // set position of hoverLine
                    hoverLine.attr("x1", mouseX).attr("x2", mouseX);

                } else {
                    // proactively act as if we've left the area since we're out of the bounds we want
                    handleMouseOutGraph(event);
                }
            } //end handleMouseOverGraph

        var handleMouseOutGraph = function(event) {
            console.log("MouseOut graph")
                // hide the hover-line
            hoverLine.classed("hide", true);
            hoverLine.attr('stroke-width', 0);
        }

        var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
            return d.timestamp;
        }).left;

        var focusX = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .style("display", "none");

        focusX.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .attr("stroke", color('x'));

        focusX.append("text")
            .attr("x", 9)
            .attr("y", -9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em");

        var focusY = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .style("display", "none");

        focusY.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .attr("stroke", color('y'));

        focusY.append("text")
            .attr("x", 9)
            .attr("y", -9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em");

        var focusZ = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .style("display", "none");

        focusZ.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .attr("stroke", color('z'));

        focusZ.append("text")
            .attr("x", 9)
            .attr("y", -9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em");

        function mousemove(event) {
            var mouseX = d3.event.layerX - 6,
                mouseY = d3.event.layerY - 6,
                x0 = xScale.invert(mouseX), //timestamp Obj
                i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                d0 = data[i - 1],
                d1 = data[i];
            var span = (xScale(d1.timestamp) - xScale(d0.timestamp)),
                weight = (xScale(x0) - xScale(d0.timestamp))/span;
                dx = (d1.x * weight) + (d0.x * (1.0 - weight)),
                dy = (d1.y * weight) + (d0.y * (1.0 - weight)),
                dz = (d1.z * weight) + (d0.z * (1.0 - weight));

            if (mouseX >= 60 && mouseX <= WIDTH && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= HEIGHT) {
                    focusX.attr("display", null);
                    focusY.attr("display", null);
                    focusZ.attr("display", null);
                    focusX.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(x0) + "," + yScale(dx) + ")");
                    focusX.select("text").text(dx.toPrecision(4));
                    focusY.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(x0) + "," + yScale(dy) + ")");
                    focusY.select("text").text(dy.toPrecision(4));
                    focusZ.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(x0) + "," + yScale(dz) + ")");
                    focusZ.select("text").text(dz.toPrecision(4));
                } else {
                    focusX.attr("display", "none");
                    focusY.attr("display", "none");
                    focusZ.attr("display", "none");
                }

        }

        var legendRectSize = 18;
        var legendSpacing = 4;

        var legend = vis.selectAll('.legend')
            .data(color.domain())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'legend')
            .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
                var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2;
                var horz = 70;
                var vert = i * height + 45;
                return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
            });

        legend.append('rect')
            .attr('width', legendRectSize)
            .attr('height', legendRectSize)
            .style('fill', color)
            .style('stroke', color);

        legend.append('text')
            .attr('x', legendRectSize + 1.5 * legendSpacing)
            .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.toUpperCase();
            })

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Here is a snippet of my JS code" Yes, and it's lacking a lot of important context. Adding such context would greatly improve the quality of this question and thereby the chance of getting good reviews. Please consider adding more context by telling us the purpose of the code (in the question itself) or adding the rest of the relevant code. Preferably both. We don't mind large blocks of code, we aren't Stack Overflow where everything has to be as simple as possible :-)

Comment: @Mast I wasn't aware that long lines of codes are acceptable on CodeReview. I have made the relevant edits on my question. Thanks for telling!

Comment: I think it's well written and I don't see any particular place that does terrible things. Are you facing performance issues ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum One improvement I have thought of is to combine the similar functions of `x`, `y` and `z` for `path` and `focus`. Particularly, {`lineGenX`, `lineGenY`, `lineGenZ`} and {`focusX`, `focusY`, `focusZ`}. However, I am lacking the knowledge to do so. My functional programming skills are skill weak. Please help.